# Swift - Invalid value around character 0

Tags: ios, json, swift

I know this has been answered, but the answers on here for this error have not helped yet.

I'm trying to get data from a server and put it in a table view, but it won't show up. I have this piece of code that determines whether data is received:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to download data")
        }else {
            print("Data downloaded")
            self.parseJSON()
        }
    }
```

but it does not work. The output from the console is:

```
 Data downloaded
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

So why does the data say it is downloaded but then I get an error? My url is definitely correct.

This is my parseJSON function:

```
func parseJSON() {

    var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    do{
        jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSMutableArray

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)

    }

    var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    let locations: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonResult.count; i++)
    {

        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        let location = LocationModel()

        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        if let accented = jsonElement["Accented"] as? String,
            let unaccented = jsonElement["Unaccented"] as? String
        {

            location.accented = accented
            location.unaccented = unaccented

        }

        locations.addObject(location)

    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(locations)

    })
}
```

Here's the data from the server:

```
<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\n</head>\n<body>\n[{\"id\":\"1\",\"accented\":\"mē\",\"unaccented\":\"me\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"accented\":\"quid\",\"unaccented\":\"quid\"},{\"id\":\"3\",\"accented\":\"nihil\",\"unaccented\":\"nihil\"},{\"id\":\"4\",\"accented\":\"nōn\",\"unaccented\":\"non\"},{\"id\":\"5\",\"accented\":\"saepe\",\"unaccented\":\"saepe\"},{\"id\":\"6\",\"accented\":\"sī\",\"unaccented\":\"si\"},{\"id\":\"7\",\"accented\":\"amō, amāre, amāvī, amātum\",\"unaccented\":\"amo\"},{\"id\":\"8\",\"accented\":\"amābō tē\",\"unaccented\":\"amabo te\"},{\"id\":\"9\",\"accented\":\"cōgitō, cōgitāre, cōgitāvī, cōgitātum\",\"unaccented\":\"cogito\"},{\"id\":\"10\",\"accented\":\"dēbeō, dēbēre, dēbuī, dēbitum\",\"unaccented\":\"debeo\"},{\"id\":\"11\",\"accented\":\"dō, dare, dedī, datum\",\"unaccented\":\"do\"},{\"id\":\"12\",\"accented\":\"errō, errāre, errāvī, errātum\",\"unaccented\":\"erro\"},{\"id\":\"13\",\"accented\":\"laudō, laudāre, laudāvī, laudātum\",\"unaccented\":\"laudo\"},{\"id\":\"14\",\"accented\":\"moneō, monēre, monuī, monitum\",\"unaccented\":\"moneo\"},{\"id\":\"15\",\"accented\":\"salveō, salvēre\",\"unaccented\":\"salveo\"},{\"id\":\"16\",\"accented\":\"salvē, salvēte\",\"unaccented\":\"salve\"},{\"id\":\"17\",\"accented\":\"servō, servāre, servāvī, servātum\",\"unaccented\":\"servo\"},{\"id\":\"18\",\"accented\":\"cōnservō, cōnservāre, cōnservāvī, cōnservātum\",\"unaccented\":\"conservo\"},{\"id\":\"19\",\"accented\":\"terreō, terrēre, terruī, territum\",\"unaccented\":\"terreo\"},{\"id\":\"20\",\"accented\":\"valeō, valēre, valuī, valitūrum\",\"unaccented\":\"valeo\"},{\"id\":\"21\",\"accented\":\"valē, valēte\",\"unaccented\":\"vale\"},{\"id\":\"22\",\"accented\":\"videō, vidēre, vīdī, vīsum\",\"unaccented\":\"video\"},{\"id\":\"23\",\"accented\":\"vocō, vocāre, vocāvī, vocātum\",\"unaccented\":\"voco\"}]</body>\n</html>
```

Comment: What's `self.data`? What's the value of it? It looks like it is not JSON.

Comment: Your URL may be correct, but it seems that the JSON returned by your server isn't.  Either post it here or validate it with an online validator such as jsonlint.com

Comment: @Paulw11 I just updated the question with the data.

Comment: @YoungDeezie - Are you 100% that this _is_ what the server returned, or is this just what you expected the server to return. You error suggests that the response wasn't JSON, even though what you say was returned looks OK. You might watch the request and the response with [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and make sure. Or convert the `NSData` to a `String` and look at that.

Comment: @Rob I went to the website url that I put in and that is all that it showed on the page.

Comment: Yeah, but that's no guarantee that that's what was returned by the server in response to the request you created via code. The error suggests that it isn't. So confirm. E.g. `let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding); print(responseString);`. Or use Charles. Also, you might look at the `statusCode`, e.g. `let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse { print(httpResponse.statusCode) }` and make sure it's `200`.

Comment: @Rob That is the problem. I'll add what the app gets to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112631/discussion-between-young-deezie-and-rob).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the response from the server is not JSON. It's an HTML response, whose `<BODY>` is JSON. You have to remove those HTML tags from the response body.

---

In chat, we discovered that your PHP currently says:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
</head> 
<body> 
<?php 

require 'database_data.php'; 

$dbc = mysqli_connect($site, $username, $password,$db) OR die('ERROR! Could not connect to the database.'); 

mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8'); 

$query = 'SELECT * FROM database'; 

if ($result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)) 
{ 
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one 
    // to hold the data 
    $resultArray = array(); 
    $tempArray = array(); 

    // Loop through each row in the result set 
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
    { 
        // Add each row into our results array 
        $tempArray = $row; 
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray); 
    } 

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results 
    echo json_encode($resultArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 
} 
?> 
</body> 
</html>
```

You should remove the HTML tags from the file. It should just be:

```
<?php 

require 'database_data.php'; 

$dbc = mysqli_connect($site, $username, $password,$db) OR die('ERROR! Could not connect to the database.'); 

mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8'); 

$query = 'SELECT * FROM database'; 

if ($result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)) 
{ 
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one 
    // to hold the data 
    $resultArray = array(); 
    $tempArray = array(); 

    // Loop through each row in the result set 
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
    { 
        // Add each row into our results array 
        $tempArray = $row; 
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray); 
    } 

    mysqli_close($dbc); 

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results 
    header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    echo json_encode($resultArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 
} 
?>
```

Also note that I added `Content-Type` header so that the response is properly formatted as JSON.

Personally, I'd be inclined to change the failure to also output JSON rather than just calling `die` (so that the app can gracefully detect the error), but that's less critical.